# On a curve $\mathcal{O}(p)\cong \mathcal{O}(q)$ implies the curve is $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ in Ravi Vakil's notes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Ravi Vaki's notes he proves then if a curve (projective, geometrically regular/integral) over field $k$ has a degree one line bundle with two or more global sections, then that curve is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1_k$.

He immediately states as a corollary that if $C$ is a curve not isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ then for any two distinct points $p,q$, $\mathcal{O}(p)\cong \mathcal{O}(q)$ cannot be true.

This seemingly should follow immediately, but I am just missing the step. What line bundle would have two sections in the above case?

Thank you for any help or direction.

Comment: Something is missing in you first statement. That is obviously wrong.

Comment: yeah oops. I meant that the line bundle must also be degree one. Thanks I have edited now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line bundle $\mathcal{L} \cong \mathcal{O}(p) \cong \mathcal{O}(q)$ is of degree one by definition. The fact that it is isomorphic to both $\mathcal{O}(p)$ and $\mathcal{O}(q)$ means it has a global section $s_1$ whose divisor (i.e. vanishing set) is $p$ and a section $s_2$ whose divisor is $q$. These are clearly different (linearly independent) sections in $H^0(\mathcal{L})$ since they have different divisors and so $\mathcal{L}$ has two global sections.

Comment: makes sense thank you